Conditional merging of vector layers in QGIS with optional input
I need to merge 3 vectors after they have executed a buffer, but 1 of them is optional, and if it is not provided, the merge should simply be done with the remaining two.
I have set up the conditional branch that you see in the photo, and indeed if I do not insert the optional input, it is not executed, but the problem is that then it does not perform the merge of the other two either. How can I solve this?


If your model stays simple you can create two Merge braches:

One with the three buffered layers as inputs,
and one with only the two mandatory layers.

And set the dependencies of each to either branch:


Yes, I had thought of this solution. The model in the picture is a simplification because, in reality, there are other algorithms after the merge, and there are 3 optional inputs out of 5. So, if there were another way, it would be better; otherwise, things would get incredibly complicated.

Use a conditional branch with @3rdLayer IS NOT NULL and the other one with @3rdLayer IS NULL.
And for further algorithms, I think you can select the correct output to use with a CASE WHEN.
